# What are some variants of the rod cutting problem?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I am looking at the possible implementations for solving the rod cutting problem (CLRS). Do you know of any variants of this problem and their use in industry?

Comment: I remember one 2D variant as the *Guillotine problem* -> paper industry.

Comment: Did you have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) yet? You should find more problems and references from there.

Comment: I think you have in mind a different problem.

Answer (score -3):

Rod Cutting Problem have many variations, One is with lenghts like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

And another are with lenghts like 1, 5, 6, 8, 13, 15, 16, 19, 21, 22

Comment: I don't see a *variant of the rod cutting problem* here, or a reference to (use in) industry.